# Is it good practice to use for loops to sort out data in the same function where it's fetched in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I am using fetch to get some data from an API, I convert this to JSON and want to sort it into different categories. For example tickets (which is what I'm retrieving) with the status active should be in a different array than the ones with status waiting on customer. I want to use a for loop to sort through the results. Should I do this in the same function they're fetched in?

Did a bit of googling but couldn't find a post on this.

```
methods: {
    fetchTickets() {
        fetch('/api')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resJson => {
            arrayLength = resJson.length
            for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                if(resJson[i]['status'] === 'active') {
                    //do something
                }
                else if(resJson[i]['status'] === 'waiting on customer') {
                    // do something else
                }
                else {
                    // do a dance
                }
            }
        });
    },
}
```

So, is it okay to do the above or is it very sensitive to errors/is there a more convenient alternative?

Comment: This is highly opinionated; for that I am voting to close

Comment: If you have working code and want it improved, consider asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Make sure you read their rules about what you can and can't post though, in case this question is off-topic on there as it stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a more convient alternative.

You should create two API calls.

```
1.) /api/activeUsers
2.) /api/waitingCustomers
```

Then for each API call, you can use the `.filter` API and return the appropiate array

```
 fetchActiveTickets() {
        fetch('/api')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resJson => {
              return resJson.filter(item => {
                       return item.status ==='active'
                     })
              //do the same for waiting... i.e. resJson(item => {
             //return item.status ==='waiting'
             //})

            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: This works, but I decided to filter it in the Laravel controllers. Counting also needs to be done, so I'll handle that stuff in the backend and just pass a array with the integer and sometimes tickets to the front.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using .filter() rather than looping over the array to split the source into the pieces you want.

```
data: {
    activeTickets: [],
    waitingTickets: []
}
methods: {
    fetchTickets() {
        fetch('/api')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resJson => {
            this.activeTickets = resJson.filter(function(ticket) { return ticket.status === 'active' });
            this.waitingTickets= resJson.filter(function(ticket) { return ticket.status === 'waiting on customer' });

            // do things with your filters arrays...  

        });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
methods: {
  async fetchTickets() {
    let res = await (await fetch('/api')).json();
    let active  = res.filter(x=> x['status']=='active');
    let waiting = res.filter(x=> x['status']=='waiting on customer');
    // ... do something
  },
}
```